# How do I efficiently replace a storage array in Solidity?

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity

I have the following function in Solidity which takes as arguments 2 arrays, an array of shareholder addresses and an array of their stakes. I'm keeping an array of shareholders in storage, together with a map to their stakes.

If the updated array is the same size, it's simple, just overwrite each position with the new values. If they are different sizes however, I first go through the entire array and delete each element, and then insert the new ones. I feel this is not very efficient and it could be done better.

PS: I am a complete beginner to Solidity and this is my first contract, so please feel free to let me know if I'm doing anything stupid or inefficiently.

Thanks !

```
function setShareholders(address[] _shareholders, uint256[] _stakes) public onlyCEO {
    require(_shareholders.length > 0);
    require(_shareholders.length == _stakes.length);
    uint256 accummulator = 0;
    for(uint8 x = 0; x < _stakes.length; x++){
      require(_addressNotNull(_shareholders[x]));
      require(_stakes[x] > 0 && _stakes[x] <= 100);
      accummulator = SafeMath.add(accummulator, _stakes[x]);
    }
    if(accummulator == 100){ // stakes need to add up to 100%
      _setShareholders(_shareholders, _stakes);
    }
  }

function _setShareholders(address[] _shareholders, uint256[] _stakes) private {
    if(_shareholders.length == shareholders.length){
      for(uint8 x = 0; x < shareholders.length; x++) {
        shareholders[x] = _shareholders[x];
        shareholderToStake[_shareholders[x]] = _stakes[x];
      }
    }
    else {
      for(x = 0; x < shareholders.length; x++) {
        delete shareholders[x];
        shareholders.length--;
        delete shareholderToStake[shareholders[x]];
      }
      for(x = 0; x < _shareholders.length; x++) {
        shareholders.push(_shareholders[x]);
        shareholderToStake[_shareholders[x]] = _stakes[x];
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this would work...unfortunately in solidity, managing arrays is a costly nightmare. Doing any array manipulation, on not just one but 2 arrays, is not recommended at all.

You could keep your array of shareholders...but from there, I'd recommend creating a mapping of **address->structure**. This way you can loop through your mapped structure and contain all necessary data within that.

So something like this for your refactor:

```
address[] public shareholders;

struct ShareHolder {
  uint stake;
  // ...other awesome data here
}

mapping (address => ShareHolder) public shareholderData;
```

This way, you have your `shareholders` list. And you can directly access a shareholder with `shareholderData[<SHAREHOLDER ADDRESS>]`.

Comment: In your code I assume you meant to write `mapping (address => ShareHolder) public shareholderData;` right ? Also, there is still the issue of replacing shareholders. By following this approach I basically have to delete entries in just the shareholders array, and not from the shareholderToStake map if I am not mistaken, which would be better indeed. I still feel there's a better way of clearing out the shareholders array though.

Comment: @c0mpute correct! As I mentioned in the answer as well. Updated. Created the code on the fly. Good catch!

Comment: @c0mpute And the idea here is not to delete anything in the `shareholders` array, but to do all of your validation based on your `ShareHolder` structure in the `shareholderData`. So you can add whatever parameters in the struct itself like `bool stillShareholder`.